# how to use singleton pattern for sequence number creation in java

Tags: java, singleton

I have an Orders class and i need to have a singleton pattern to be able to create a sequence number for each order processed. How do i implement this?

My order class has an Order_ID, Customer_ID, Order_desc and Ordered_qty. There needs to be a sequence number created for each order processed using the singleton pattern.

Comment: This does not seem like a good use of the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Why do you need to generate the sequence outside of the database?

Comment: Is this homework or an assignment?

Comment: yes assignment. i have to use the Singleton pattern to allocate a sequence number to each order.

Comment: OK, if that is an assignment - what did **you** try to do?

Comment: I was just writing an answer to this question to help you.  I wrote code that did exactly what you needed and then the rest of my answer was explaining why it is a bad idea.  Now that I know this is a homework assignment, the rationale behind this approach is irrelevant and I don't want to just give you an answer to a homework assignment.  Since others have already done so, I will go ahead and share mine.  Next time, please be upfront about these situations so people can give an appropriate answer.

Comment: This is proof that a well posed question gets answered even when it's homework! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be one of those X/Y problems, where you think Y is a solution to X, so you ask for help with Y, but perhaps there is a better solution.

Strictly speaking, to implement a singleton, all you need is a class whose only constructors are private, a static reference to an instance of the class as a class field, and a public getInstance method.  Then create an instance method which returns the next number in line.

```
public class MySingleton {
    private static MySingleton instance = new MySingleton();

    private volatile int next = 0;

    private MySingleton() {
        // prevent external instantiation of a singleton.
    }

    public static MySingleton getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public synchronized int getNextSequence() {
        return next++;
    }
}
```

There are many flaws with this solution to your problem, some are just basic OOP design and some are more systemic:

1. A singleton that does not implement or extend any types is worthless.  You could just use all static methods instead.  Singletons are useful if you are writing a class that implements an interface and that interface is used by somebody else, but you only want a single instance as an implementation detail.  This type of singleton is an attempt to make a global variable look like it is not a global variable.
2. This will not survive application restarts.  If these sequences are being used to identify data that is stored externally or shared, you will end up repeating the same numbers when the application is restarted.
3. If you deploy multiple instances of the application who read and write to a common persistent storage, like a database, they will re-use the same numbers because the sequence is only tracked within the JVM.
4. Databases are already exceptionally good at this.  Trying to re-invent it in the application tier seems.... inappropriate.

Comment: the `getInstance` method should be static.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon method is synchronized

Comment: @Brandon, your singleton suffers from more issues: http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/10/22/singleton-design-pattern-in-java/

Comment: Creating the singleton instance before it is needed is not a concern because 1) it only has a single instance variable, an integer. 2) The only thing we can use the class for is using an instance method, so loading the class without getting the instance is silly.

Comment: @-G-Man thanks for the feedback.  I know about the double-checking lock technique, but didn't see a need for lazy initialization here.  This is a bad use for singleton pattern anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree @Elliott Frisch that the question itself sounds strange. However if you indeed have to generate IDs yourself here is the prototype that implements *classic* version of Singleton pattern.

```
public class IdGenerator {
    private  static IdGenerator instance;
    private int id = 0;
    private IdGenerator(){}
    private static IdGenerator getInstance() {
        synchronized(IdGenerator.class) {
           if (instance == null) {
                instance = new IdGenerator();
           }
           return instance;
        }
    }

    public int nextId() {
        return id++;
    }
}
```

Please note that word "classic". There are a lot of possible improvements of Singleton pattern and there are hundreds of articles that explain them.

Answer (score 0):

The key aspect is to use a single [AtomicLong](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) as the singleton. You may model it like this:

```
class Orders {

    private static final AtomicLong NEXT_ID = new AtomicLong();

    static Order newOrder(Customer customer, String description, int quantity) {
        return new Order(orderId(), customer, description, quantity);
    }

    private static long orderId() {
        return NEXT_ID.incrementAndGet();
    }
}

class Order {

    private final long orderId;
    private final long customerId;
    private final String description;
    private final int quantity;

    Order(long orderId, Customer customer, String description, int quantity) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.customerId = customer.getCustomerId();
        this.description = description;
    }

}

class Customer {

    public long getCustomerId() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not yet implemented");
    }
}
```